# How to get youtube videos using feed from username?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I want to retrieve all the videos that are related to same user  on YouTube. 
how can I do that?
there is a link : https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/playlists?v=2 but I do not Know what to put in user id field .

Comment: Maybe try the YouTube API : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Retrieving_playlists

Comment: or google: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/ :-)

Comment: @Tolen - Even though it seems to me like the exact thing you're in a need of, please return here and tell if it fits your needs. Thanks

Comment: @g00dy:I have concluded to use the link below: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/playlists?v=2 but I do not know yet what to put in user id feild

Comment: I found another interesting thing, just below the one you provided: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:username

Comment: @g00dy: Are you suggest to me to search the user name on an execute query and use result in another execute query in order to find the username?

Comment: @Tolen I actually thought, that you have the username already and that  the problem is in the userId ..

Comment: @g00dy: In fact I want to enter any username and find the videos related to him/her. anyway thank you a lot I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Tolen - welcome, you can paste the solution you've gotten and accept it even :)

Comment: I did not came up  with any solution I am so confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=username&v=2&alt=json

and put it in your execute statement ...